# Getting arguments out of a C function using SWIG

Tags: python, swig

I have the following SWIG file (simplified of course):

```
typedef int64_t SuiteSparse_long;

%apply SuiteSparse_long  *OUTPUT {
     SuiteSparse_long  *lnz,
     SuiteSparse_long  *unz,
     SuiteSparse_long  *n_row,
     SuiteSparse_long  *n_col,
     SuiteSparse_long  *nz_udiag
 };

SuiteSparse_long umfpack_dl_get_lunz
(
    SuiteSparse_long *lnz,
    SuiteSparse_long *unz,
    SuiteSparse_long *n_row,
    SuiteSparse_long *n_col,
    SuiteSparse_long *nz_udiag,
    void *Numeric
) ;
```

And I expected the Python function signature to be:

```
umfpack_zl_get_lunz(void * Numeric) -> (SuiteSparse_long, SuiteSparse_long lnz, SuiteSparse_long unz, SuiteSparse_long n_row, SuiteSparse_long n_col)
```

However, the actual Python function signature was

```
umfpack_zl_get_lunz(SuiteSparse_long * lnz, SuiteSparse_long * unz, SuiteSparse_long * n_row, SuiteSparse_long * n_col,
            SuiteSparse_long * nz_udiag, void * Numeric) -> SuiteSparse_long
```

Interestingly, when I `typedef long SuiteSpare_long`, it works, but not with `int64_t`. Does SWIG not support `int64_t`?

Comment: it seems that its only uint64,int64, and int64_array. 
http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html

Comment: Is there an alternative solution to the problem?

Comment: have you tried _int64?

Comment: No, but _int64 is not a standardized type AFAIK. Does SWIG support that?

Comment: I know it won't be signed for exactly 64 bits... but according to SWIG docs, it does support __int64 (for windows env). Never used it, but recommendation is to take a quick read through the docs.

Comment: The solution was to %apply long rather than %apply sparsesuite_long